# C++, error c2143 (syntax errot),c2065,c2109

Tags: arrays, syntax-error

I'm very new to programming

I am getting these compiler errors:

Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
Error   2   error C2065: 'ary' : undeclared identifier
Error   3   error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
Error   4   error C2065: 'ary' : undeclared identifier
Error   5   error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

Here is my code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
    int num, sum, i, e, n, avrg, numsnum, avrgu, chek;
    sum = 0; 
    i = 0;
    avrgu = 0;
    chek = 0;
    n = 0;
    numsnum = 0;
    int ary[5];
    e = 0;

    do{
        scanf("%d", &num);
        ary[n] = num;
        n++;
        i++;
        sum += num;
        numsnum++;
    } while (i != 4);

    avrg = (sum) / numsnum;
    for (e = 0; e = 4; e++){
        if (ary[chek] > avrg){
            avrgu++;
        }
        chek++;
    }
    printf("%d numbers are above the AVERAGE of all.\n", avrgu);


    return 0;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you've entered here is erroneous. Can you kindly recheck and edit it..?

Comment: Just put a comment on the line where you get the error(s). Please?! :)

Comment: error 1: line 11
error 2: line 16
error 3:line 16
error 4: line 25
error 5: line 25

Comment: i have tried both (VS 2012 and VS 2013), the errors are somehow connect to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is that you find some good introductory C++ tutorials. The internet is full of them, just do a quick search on Google. Here is one I found quickly: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson1.html

The problem with your code above is that you are indexing off the end of your array `ary`. This is happening inside your `for` loop: for (e = 0; **e = 4;** e++). Your for loop check is assigning `e` the value of 4. What you probably meant to do was `e == 4`, but even that isn't quite right. What you want to do is to continue looping while `e < 4`.

Below is a revised version of your code:

```
// C++ version of stdio.h
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Create an array of five doubles and
    // initialize all the doubles to 0
    double array[5] = {};

    double num = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double count = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        // Read the user input from the console
        std::cin >> num;
        array[i] = num;
        sum += num;
    }

    double average = sum / count;

    int numbersAboveAverage = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] > average)
        {
            numbersAboveAverage++;
        }
    }

    // Print the numbersAboveAverage value to the console.
    std::cout << numbersAboveAverage
         << " numbers are above the average.\n" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I would recommend that you do some more reading, and make sure you keep programming! The best way to learn is by doing. I hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: but why it gives me this error "Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type' line 11" ??

Comment: Not totally sure, since I wasn't getting that error when I tried to run your code. If I had to guess I would say you were missing a semi colon somewhere, or you had misspelled the primitive type on a variable declaration.

Comment: @pje well try after running after that put 5 numbers.
for me everytime i reach the fifth number it crashes.